# What is a good resource for functional derivatives and functional determinants?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, online-resources

What is a good resource for functional derivatives, functional determinants,  etc.? What is the branch of mathematics dealing with those things? It is not in my functional analysis book. What is a good resource on functionals in general?

Comment: This might not be what you want, but most books treating non-linear PDE tend to have a chapter or two of introductory nature about these topics.

Comment: Did you find one?